Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using 'python.exe' and 'pip.exe'
I am encountering an issue while trying to use pip to install packages in Python on Windows. Whenever I run pip install package_name or any pip command, I get the following error message:
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" install package_name': The system cannot find the file specified.

Steps Taken:
Checked Python Installation: Confirmed that Python and pip are installed correctly by running python --version and pip --version
Verified Environment Variables: Ensured that the Python installation directory (C:\Program Files\Python310\ and C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\) is included in the PATH environment variable.
Reinstalled Python: Reinstalled Python from scratch, ensuring to include Python in PATH during installation.
Disabled Antivirus: Temporarily disabled antivirus software to check if it was causing interference

Can you try python -m pip install package_name?

When i started using Python i struggled with the same problem, initially i decided to use PyCharm Community IDE, i configured the python interpreter, went to the terminal and runned the command pip install package_name and it worked, this was my initial way to solve the problem.
I don't know if you to program from the terminal, but I strongly recommend an IDE it will help you to write code better and faster and fro me it's easier to manage your projects from an IDE like PyCharm Community than from the terminal.
However if you plan to solve this problem from the terminal try running the next command to bypass the issue: python -m pip install package_name or try checking the path is correct, run where python and where pip it will give you the path of the directory where they are installed.
